# Can I use a Trinket as a material component?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, spell-components

I was going to create a wizard with the sailor background. Now the Sailor starting equipment in the PHB states that I get a lucky charm. Either a rabbit foot, small stone with a hole in it, or something from the trinkets table. I rolled a gemstone that looks like coal when inspected by someone else other than me. Also to mention that this gemstone does not specify a price.

1. Could this gemstone be a diamond?
2. Can I use this to cast chromatic orb?

Comment: Given the tag, I assume this is in an AL game?

Answer (score 22):

### Rules As Written? Indeterminate.

The rules are silent on the value of trinkets, but sure... it could be a diamond.

### Balanced? No.

The diamond required for Chromatic Orb has a minimum value requirement. Allowing a freebie "trinket" to count as something worth 50 GP drastically increases the character's starting resources.

### D&D Adventurers' League? No.

DDAL tracks treasure awarded and treasure spent. If you didn't log recieving the cash and didn't log spending the cash, you don't have the object.

Answer (score 5):

#### If this works, many spell components become superfluous

The *[prestidigitation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation)* spell can create "nonmagical trinkets" which last until the end of your next turn. That's long enough that you could, say, conjure a jade circlet and then use it to cast *[shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange)* for free instead of spending 1500 gp. That's clearly not how spell components are intended to work.

Comment: I think you're thinking of [Shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange), not [Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph).

Answer (score -3):

Rules as intended, I do not believe trinkets are supposed to have any mechanical value.

As a DM, I would let the trinket be made of whatever you want, but I would not let you use it for anything other than role playing and I would not let you sell it for more than a few copper.

Answer (score -7):

### 1. Absolutely

### 2. Only if you deduct 50 GP from your starting gold.

<strike>Unless your DM tells you otherwise.</strike>

The cost of the components is for balancing so you can't ignore them without consequences.

Comment: The question is flagged DDAL organized play, so there is no individual DM that can authorize something-for-nothing.